# How can I avoid this Error : Verify Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 99?

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, cobertura

I'm running Junit Tests in my project (using Maven and Cobertura), and I have this Error that said :

```
Verify Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 99
```

-Configuration :

```
Java : 8
Maven : 4.0.0
```

How can I avoid this by using Java 8, because I can't use another version before 8.
It appears thar this line below in my classTest is the problem :

```
Sinus test = new Sinus();
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I just verified that when I use the cmd : 

    'mvn test'

I have no Errors, but if I use the cmd :

'mvn cobertura:cobertuta' 

This Error appears ! And I don't have any clue why !!

Comment: `cobertura:cobertuta` - maybe typo
try: `cobertura:cobertura`

Comment: @AnsarOzden I don't understand what I should do ?

Comment: I tried 'mvn try cobertura:cobertura' but it didn't work